# What H.G. Wells mean with the phrase 'a morning star of hope'?

Tags: meaning, literature

[In this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/131409/6795) a quote from H.G. Wells "War of the Worlds" was posted:

> That last stage of exhaustion, which to us is still incredibly remote,
>   has become a present-day problem for the inhabitants of Mars. The
>   immediate pressure of necessity has brightened their intellects,
>   enlarged their powers, and hardened their hearts. And looking across
>   space with instruments, and intelligences such as we have scarcely
>   dreamed of, they see, at its nearest distance only 35,000,000 of miles
>   sunward of them, **a morning star of hope**, our own warmer planet, green
>   with vegetation and grey with water, with a cloudy atmosphere eloquent
>   of fertility, with glimpses through its drifting cloud wisps of broad
>   stretches of populous country and narrow, navy-crowded seas.

The phrase "a morning star of hope" caught my eye. Is this a biblical reference to Lucifer? Perhaps a foreshadowing to the eventual fate of the martians?

Can someone help me understand what exactly H.G. Wells is trying to say with this phrase?

Comment: This is, ultimately, litcrit, which, though I wish we supported on this site (at least for the better questions, like this one), we don't. It's off-topic (see the [help/on-topic]). We only tend to address questions on the mechanics of English (grammar, orthography, etymology, etc). But in short: our *morning star*, on Earth, the brightest "star" in the sky at the time, the harbinger of a brand new day and all its possibilities, is actually the planet Venus. You know, the planet one orbit closer to the Sun. Similarly, on Mars, the planet one orbit closer to the Sun is Earth...

Comment: Searching "morning star of hope" on Google gives [this](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/morning+star) as the first answer : "A planet, especially Venus, visible in the east just before or at sunrise." confirming @DanBron 's answer.  So not only is this off-topic, it's also 'general reference'.

Comment: @DanBron Oh I'm sorry I hadn't realized literature questions where off topic here. I'll flag for closure. Thank you for the information though!

Comment: @TrevorD So sorry; I've already flagged to close the question.

Comment: @asawyer That's OK - so have I!  I think that if it's your own question, you should be able to delete it anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the risk of engaging in literary criticism, H G Wells was not a Christian, and it is unlikely that he uses the term as a reference to Lucifer. In fact the Christian usage is not the most common usage of 'morning star'.

'Morning star' refers to the planet Venus, which is bright in the sky and is close to the sun. This means that it can often be seen just before the dawn, hence the name, and so it is a kind of indication that the sun is about to rise.

The use of 'morning star' here is very probably as a metaphorical herald of a metaphorical dawn for the Martians, an indication that their fate may be avoidable. Also since Earth is closer to the Sun than Mars, the planet Earth functions as a literal morning star to the Martians, in much the same way that Venus does to us.